# Find messages from certain key till certain key while being able to remove stale keys

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, concurrent-collections

### My problem

Let's say I want to hold my messages in some sort of datastructure for longpolling application:

```
1. "dude"
2. "where"
3. "is"
4. "my"
5. "car"
```

Asking for messages from index[4,5] should return:
 `"my","car"`.

Next let's assume that after a while I would like to purge old messages because they aren't useful anymore and I want to save memory. Let's say after time `x` messages[1-3] became stale. I assume that it would be most efficient to just do the deletion once every `x` seconds. Next my datastructure should contain:

```
4. "my"
5. "car"
```

### My solution?

I was thinking of using a `concurrentskiplistset` or `concurrentskiplist` map. Also I was thinking of deleting the old messages from inside a `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`. I would like to know how you would implement(efficiently/thread-safe) this or maybe use a library?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the functional requirement, but have you considered [`WeakHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)? The entries will be automagically removed by the GC when no longer referenced somewhere else. Again, not sure if that's what you're looking for, the functional requirement is vague and ambiguous. "return messages from certain key to certain key" makes little sense to me.

Comment: Sorry If I was not clear about it. I will try to rewrite my answer a little bit. I don't have experience with WeakHashMap

Comment: The question is more clear. I only miss one point: based on what conditions would you determine if they are stale?

Comment: I want to implement simple long polling. I just want to delete messages after a little while to save memory. I think 1 minute is enough for the long polling.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how do you know *which* messages needs to be deleted? If you want to remove them after a minute, then you'll need to hold a timestamp somewhere along the message and use that in the conditional check.

Comment: you are right about that. But I guess you could just simply store the last value in an atomicinteger(increment) or something and when you do clean up save the last value in another atomicinteger and compare it with the current value. Then delete the old messages or something.

Comment: Feasible, but what if the integer overflows when its max is reached? Isn't it an option to just shift up the newer messages to the beginning of the index? Or do you really need a fixed index/key-based retrieval?

Comment: Okay I just want to retrieve messages which I have not yet reveived. How it is done I don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big concern, as I gather it, is how to let certain elements expire after a period.  I had a similar requirement and I created a message class that implemented the [Delayed Interface](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html).  This class held everything I needed for a message and (through the Delayed interface) told me when it has expired.

I used instances of this object within a concurrent collection, you could use a [ConcurrentMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) because it will allow you to key those objects with an integer key.

I reaped the collection once every so often, removing items whose delay has passed. We test for expiration by using the getDelay method of the Delayed interface:

```
message.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I used a normal thread that would sleep for a period then reap the expired items.  In my requirements it wasn't important that the items be removed as soon as their delay had expired.  It seems that you have a similar flexibility.

If you needed to remove items as soon as their delay expired, then instead of sleeping a set period in your reaping thread, you would sleep for the delay of the message that will expire first.

Here's my delayed message class:

```
class DelayedMessage implements Delayed {

    long endOfDelay;
    Date requestTime;
    String message;

    public DelayedMessage(String m, int delay) {
        requestTime = new Date();
        endOfDelay = System.currentTimeMillis()
                + delay;
        this.message = m;
    }

    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        long delay = unit.convert(
                endOfDelay - System.currentTimeMillis(),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return delay;
    }

    public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
        DelayedMessage that = (DelayedMessage) o;
        if (this.endOfDelay < that.endOfDelay) {
            return -1;

        }
        if (this.endOfDelay > that.endOfDelay) {
            return 1;
        }
        return this.requestTime.compareTo(that.requestTime);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but it looks like you need a `NavigableMap<K,V>` to me.

```
import java.util.*;
public class NaviMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NavigableMap<Integer,String> nmap = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        nmap.put(1, "dude");
        nmap.put(2, "where");
        nmap.put(3, "is");
        nmap.put(4, "my");
        nmap.put(5, "car");

        System.out.println(nmap);
        // prints "{1=dude, 2=where, 3=is, 4=my, 5=car}"        

        System.out.println(nmap.subMap(4, true,  5, true).values());
        // prints "[my, car]"              ^inclusive^  

        nmap.subMap(1, true, 3, true).clear();
        System.out.println(nmap);
        // prints "{4=my, 5=car}"

        // wrap into synchronized SortedMap
        SortedMap<Integer,String> ssmap =Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(nmap);

        System.out.println(ssmap.subMap(4, 5));
        // prints "{4=my}"                 ^exclusive upper bound!

        System.out.println(ssmap.subMap(4, 5+1));
        // prints "{4=my, 5=car}"          ^ugly but "works"
    }
}
```

Now, **unfortunately** there's no easy way to get a `synchronized` version of a `NavigableMap<K,V>`, but a `SortedMap` does have a `subMap`, but only one overload where the upper bound is strictly exclusive.

#### API links

- [`SortedMap.subMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#subMap%28K,%20K%29)
- [`NavigableMap.subMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29)
- [`Collections.synchronizedSortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSortedMap%28java.util.SortedMap%29)